# Retrieve unmatched and matched text from regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to search a Java String that can contain html and plain text.  If the html is wrapped with either a single tick `('<b>'text'<b>')` or a block of html is wrapped with three ticks `('''<html><head><title>Sample</title></head><body><div>text</div></body></html>''')`, I need to not remove the html from the String.  If the html is not wrapped with a single or triple tick then I need to remove the html.

The below works fine if the content is not mixed.  I want to modify it such that if the 
`String value="non <b>ticked</b> content <u>here</u> and '<b>'mixed'</b>' content '<u>'here'</u>'` would get written to memory/returned as `non ticked content here and '<b>'mixed'</b>' content '<u>'here'</u>'`.

I believe I need to change the regex to only pass the non-ticked (single or tripple) content to my jsoup html2text method.  Any ideas on how to change the regex or logic such that only the non-ticked content is passed to html2text method?  If I pass in the whole string (with ticked content) to jsoup it will remove all html, which isn't desired.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class HtmlSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HtmlSerializer.class);
  private static final Pattern singlePattern = Pattern.compile("'.*'");
  private static final Pattern blockPattern = Pattern.compile("'''.*'''");

  protected HtmlSerializer() {
    super(String.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
      JsonGenerationException {
      if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)){
          Matcher blockMatcher = blockPattern.matcher(value);
          Matcher singleMatcher = singlePattern.matcher(value);
          if(!blockMatcher.find() && !singleMatcher.find()){
              jgen.writeString(html2text(value));
          }else{
              jgen.writeString(value);
          }
      }else{
          jgen.writeString(value);
      }  
  }

  private static String html2text(String html) {
        return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern does not work correctly because `.*` matches as much as it can. Therefore `'.*'` will match from the very first occurrence of `'` up to the very last occurrence of `'` regardless of how many `'` are in between. In your example it will match the entire sequence `'<b>'mixed'</b>' content '<u>'here'</u>'`.

To fix this, the easiest way is to use the “reluctant quantifier”. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)
`'.*?'` will match as little as possible and therefore stop at the very next occurence of a `'`.

The same applies to your group syntax, use `'''.*?'''`. Then you can combine both with an *or* operation to find all your quoted constructs: `'''.*?'''|'.*?'`. It’s important to specify the triple quote first as they otherwise would be treated like multiple single quoted strings.

Then the processing has to work on the *substrings* like this:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("'''.*?'''|'.*?'");
Matcher m=p.matcher(value);
int normalPos=0, length=value.length();
while(normalPos<length && m.find())
{
  int quotePos=m.start(), quoteEnd=m.end();
  if(normalPos<quotePos) processNormally(value.substring(normalPos, quotePos));
  final boolean tripleQuote=m.end()-m.start()>=6 && value.charAt(quotePos+1)=='\'';
  final int skip=tripleQuote? 3: 1;
  processQuoted(value.substring(quotePos+skip, quoteEnd-skip));
  normalPos=quoteEnd;
}
if(normalPos<length) processNormally(value.substring(normalPos));
```